# Loading ~/.emacs: cannot open load file, php-mode

Tags: init-file, package-repositories, load-path

GNU Emacs 24.5.1, installed MELPA, installed php-mode. The directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/php-mode-20180105.541/` exists.

I added the following lines to `.emacs`:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/elpa")
(require 'php-mode)
```

I presume it's that last line that's triggering the error. I ran `C-h v load-path` and it includes `~/.emacs.d/elpa/php-mode-20180105.541/`

`emacs --debug-init` didn't help me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're mixing up `require` with using a package. When you say `(require 'php-mode)` Emacs looks for a file (or a feature) named `php-mode` in your `load-path`. `~/.emacs.d/elpa` is in your `load-path`, but there is no file `php-mode.el` in that directory.

You'll need to use the package system, not `require`, if you expect Emacs to dig into a package directory.

Or if there is a file `php-mode.el[c]` in directory `~/.emacs.d/elpa/php-mode-20180105.541/` then add *that* directory to your `load-path` before using `require`. (And I think you forgot the `~/`, at least in your question, if not in fact.)

Comment: Okay, I understand. I didn't realize that the package system did more than install packages. That clears things up considerably. Thx.